# pyenv prints module in terminal when executing said module

Tags: pyenv

I've moved over to using `pyenv` when running python.  The problem though is when I execute a module and that module imports other module `pyenv` will often print a huge chunk of what to me is gibberish.  For example,

```
alias py37="pyenv local 3.7.3 && python"


Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:general kylefoley$ py37
Python 3.7.3 (default, Oct 16 2019, 03:01:07) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keyboard
bool b'B' <classmethod object at 0x10a7317f0> <function ivar.bool at 0x10bf8b8c8>
char b'c' <classmethod object at 0x10a731898> <function ivar.char at 0x10bf8b950>
int b'i' <classmethod object at 0x10a763160> <function ivar.int at 0x10bf8b9d8>
short b's' <classmethod object at 0x10a776b70> <function ivar.short at 0x10bf8ba60>
long b'l' <classmethod object at 0x10a781cc0> <function ivar.long at 0x10bf8bae8>
long_long b'q' <classmethod object at 0x10b819f98> <function ivar.long_long at 0x10bf8bb70>
```

As you can see when I imported the module `keyboard` I got quite a lot of unwanted output.  This happens a lot with `pyenv`. What is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a debug print statement accidentally left in pyobjc 6.0. This will be fixed in version 6.0.1.
Check this [issue](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/issues/277/importing-pyobjc-prints-out-a-bunch-of) and the [commit](https://bitbucket.org/ronaldoussoren/pyobjc/commits/d4d6b573d08226ab67bc5a26f54fa1dfc0471a16) which fixes it. To fix this either downgrade to pyobjc 5.3 or wait for the fix which will be released very soon and upgrade to pyobjc 6.0.1.