# pyperclip.copy function gives a lot of unwanted output

Tags: python, import, pyperclip

I was following along with Al's Automate the boring stuff with python. I'm a relative novice with python and reading the traceback. When I first executed the pyperclip.copy() function I got a huge readout of some stuff that I can't even begin to understand. The function worked and no longer does this but can someone explain what happened and how to read/make sense of this type of output?
NOTE: When I first started programming I got a lil joy happy and went and installed anaconda 3 and similar data science tools. I have since deleted anaconda3 but can't remember what all I did install around my start in programming with python (circa 2017)

This is for automation. I've never done this before so this is just a search for more knowledge to understand what is happening.

> import pyperclip
>
> pyperclip.copy('Hello!!!!!!!')

## this should just jump to the next input line in the python IDLE shell after copying the string

this is what immediately followed the pyperclip.copy() function as an output (should have 0 output)... it is quite long but looks largely to be referencing three things: ivar dot path, CFXML files, and NS files. Not sure what these are but this is the total output:

> bool b'B'  
>   char b'c'  
>   int b'i'  
>   short b's'  
>   long b'l'  
>   long_long b'q'  
>   unsigned_char b'C'  
>   unsigned_int b'I'  
>   unsigned_short b'S'  
>   unsigned_long b'L'  
>   unsigned_long_long b'Q'  
>   float b'f'  
>   double b'd'  
>   BOOL b'Z'  
>   UniChar b'T'  
>   char_text b't'  
>   char_int b'z'  
>   CFXMLEntityInfo b'{_CFXMLEntityInfo=q^{__CFString=}{_CFXMLExternalID=^{__CFURL=}^{__CFString=}}^{__CFString=}}'  
>   CFXMLElementInfo b'{_CFXMLElementInfo=^{__CFDictionary=}^{__CFArray=}Z[3c]}'  
>   CFXMLAttributeListDeclarationInfo b'{_CFXMLAttributeListDeclarationInfo=q^{_CFXMLAttributeDeclarationInfo=^{__CFString=}^{__CFString=}^{__CFString=}}}'  
>   CFXMLElementTypeDeclarationInfo b'{_CFXMLElementTypeDeclarationInfo=^{__CFString=}}'  
>   CFGregorianDate b'{_CFGregorianDate=iccccd}'  
>   CFXMLExternalID b'{_CFXMLExternalID=^{__CFURL=}^{__CFString=}}'  
>   CFUUIDBytes b'{_CFUUIDBytes=CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC}'  
>   CFXMLAttributeDeclarationInfo b'{_CFXMLAttributeDeclarationInfo=^{__CFString=}^{__CFString=}^{__CFString=}}'  
>   CFSwappedFloat32 b'{_CFSwappedFloat32=I}'  
>   CFSwappedFloat64 b'{_CFSwappedFloat64=Q}'  
>   CFXMLDocumentTypeInfo b'{_CFXMLDocumentTypeInfo={_CFXMLExternalID=^{__CFURL=}^{__CFString=}}}'  
>   CFStreamError b'{_CFStreamError=qi}'  
>   CFXMLEntityReferenceInfo b'{_CFXMLEntityReferenceInfo=q}'  
>   CFXMLProcessingInstructionInfo b'{_CFXMLProcessingInstructionInfo=^{__CFString=}}'  
>   CFRange b'{_CFRange=qq}'  
>   CFSocketSignature b'{_CFSocketSignature=iii^{__CFData=}}'  
>   CFXMLDocumentInfo b'{_CFXMLDocumentInfo=^{__CFURL=}I}'  
>   CFGregorianUnits b'{_CFGregorianUnits=iiiiid}'  
>   CFXMLNotationInfo b'{_CFXMLNotationInfo={_CFXMLExternalID=^{__CFURL=}^{__CFString=}}}'  
>   NSEdgeInsets b'{NSEdgeInsets=dddd}'  
>   NSHashEnumerator b'{_NSHashEnumerator=QQ^v}'  
>   NSAffineTransformStruct b'{_NSAffineTransformStruct=dddddd}'  
>   NSRect b'{CGRect={CGPoint=dd}{CGSize=dd}}'  
>   NSOperatingSystemVersion b'{_NSOperatingSystemVersion=qqq}'  
>   NSZone b'{_NSZone=}'  
>   NSDecimal b'{_NSDecimal=b8b4b1b1b18[8S]}'  
>   NSSize b'{CGSize=dd}'  
>   NSPoint b'{CGPoint=dd}'  
>   NSSwappedDouble b'{_NSSwappedDouble=Q}'  
>   NSMapEnumerator b'{_NSMapEnumerator=QQ^v}'  
>   NSSwappedFloat b'{_NSSwappedFloat=I}'  
>   NSRange b'{_NSRange=QQ}'  
>   NSDirectionalEdgeInsets b'{NSDirectionalEdgeInsets=dddd}'  
>   NSOpenGLPixelFormatAuxiliary b'{_CGLPixelFormatObject=}'  
>   NSScreenAuxiliaryOpaque b'{NSScreenAuxiliary=}'  
>   NSOpenGLContextAuxiliary b'{_CGLContextObject=}'

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here, bug in PyObjC 6.0 - has since been patched.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476076/12087395